# Installing Python Linecache

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi3

I need to install the python library 'linecache' on my raspberry pi. I'm about 2 days into learning Python and imagine this might be a stupid question.

I've been using the syntax `sudo pip install linecache` for everything else I'm installing. But in this instance I'm getting the error:

> Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement linecache
>   Cleaning up... No distributions at all found for linecache

It looks like it's downloading it as it take a few minutes before this error.

Any advice for a graphic designer trying to code? Thanks Dan.

Comment: I don't know if Raspberry Pi changes anything, but ordinarily, `linecache` comes with Python. Are you sure you need to install it separately?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to install it as it is part of the standard lib.

Comment: Thanks so much. I thought I had to install it. Know this has helped me figure out the real problem. I just hadn't imported linecache to my python code.